# How to show the UITableview like as UIAlertview

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application in which I am using one UIButton.

When I click that button it needs to show the UITableView and other remaining controls are not working.
I need to show the UITableView act like a UIAlertView.

Comment: you want a table view to pop up like aler view and disable all other button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create `UITableViewController`. and present modelView as page. it works fine.

Comment: I needs to show the tableview at the center of the screen and when i click on any control out of that tableview then it's not work.Just like UIalertview,remaining controls are not respond.

Comment: self.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
    self.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    
    [self presentModalViewController:tableViewControllerObject animated:YES];    this code will helps you to display viewcontroller in center.

Comment: Remaining controls are appear or not.

Answer (score 0):

For the First part of your question, Simply add `tableview.userInteractionEnabled = NO` and so on for disabling the buttons. And if you want to make the `UIAlertView` act like a `UITableView` simply add the animation to the `UITableView`.

Or you could even make a Custom `UIAlertView`.